# Find and Replace Words that have Uppercase letters in the middle using RegEx for Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a huge list of names. Each names are separated by newline and formatted with comma like the following

```
Lastname, Firstname
Lastname, Firstname
Lastname, Firstname
Lastname, Firstname
```

But there are instances where the newline was deleted so the Firstname and Lastname got merged like this example

```
Lastname, Firstname
Lastname, FirstnameLastname, Firstname
Lastname, FirstnameLastname, Firstname
```

Using regex in Notepad++, how can I find those instances and replace them with the correct name which is separated by a new line?

Thank you!

Edit: Here's what I tried and have been doing in the past hours.

```
\w+[A-Z]\w*
```

It works in finding all the instances of accidentally combined names. What I did is I just manually edit them one by one. From 500+ instances, I'm down to 300+. Still a long way to go. Tried searching online for similar pattern but to no avail. I hope I could do it in just one click, also this might help someone in the future who're stuck in the same scenario as me right now.

Update:
The answer by toto works like a charm, so I accepted it as a correct answer. I learned something awesome today. Thanks Toto. Anyway, I already solved my problem using this approach a couple of minutes ago after experimenting with some regex I saw online.

```
Find: (\b[A-Za-z]+)([A-Z]+)([A-Za-z]+\b)
Replace: \1\n\2\3
```

It does the same thing but IMO Toto's approach is more elegant!

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your comment. I updated my question. That's my attempt to solve the problem cuz I'm not really good in regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])`
- Replace with: `\n`  or  `\r\n` depending on platform
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=[a-z])    # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a small letter before
(?=[A-Z])     # positive lookahead, make sure we have a capital after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks Toto. I'm gonna redo all the replacing using your regex. You're a lifesaver! Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

In Notepad++ you can use a pattern without lookarounds.

First match a single lowercase char `[a-z]`. Then you can make use of `\K` to forget what is matched so far, and match a single uppercase char `[A-Z]`

In the replacement use a newline followed by the match for the uppercase char by referring the to whole match using `$0`

**Find what:**

```
[a-z]\K[A-Z]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xU9gAI/1)

**Replace with:**

```
\n$0
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. My problem has been solved. But I still appreciate your answer for future reference. I tried your solution and I noticed something weird. When I replace one at a time. Nothing happened. But when I click Replace All. Somehow, it works.